# Group Theory and closure of a group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I am trying to find subgroups of $D_{10}$.
I can easily find the subgroups of order $2$ - $\{e, t\}$, $\{e, st\}, \ldots$ etc. where $s$ is the rotation of each vertices and $t$ is the reflection along the vertical line through 1.

I know that $\langle t, st\rangle$ is also a subgroup.
Now $\langle t, st\rangle = \{e, t, st, s^4, s\}$ but $s^4t$ and $s^2t$ are not in the group, therefore $\langle t, st\rangle$ is not a group! Please help me with my logic.

I was also wondering if $a, b \in D_{10}$ and $c, d\in D_{10}$ if $ab= cd$, does this count as closure? even if we were to write out the elements in $D_{10}$ and $a.b$ didn't match any of them?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $s, t\in \langle t, st\rangle$, it must be the case that $\langle t, st\rangle \supseteq \langle s, t\rangle = D_{10}$.

Your computation of the group generated by $t$ and $st$ was incomplete.

For your second question, I'm not entirely clear about what you are asking. Closure means that the product of any two elements of the set (group) is again in the set. More formally: If $a, b\in D_{10}$, then $ab\in D_{10}$.

Comment: but the order of t, st are 2. Therefore the only elements in $<t, st>$ are {e, t, st, tst, stt} so $<s, t>$ is not a subset of $<t, st>$.

Comment: $t$ and $st$ do not commute, so what you said is not the case. Moreover, you just pointed out that indeed $t\in\langle t, st\rangle$!

Comment: yes t, s are elements of $<t, st>$  but that does not mean $<t, st>$ is a subset of $<t, s>$ for example - $s^2$ is an element of $<t, s>$ but not an element of $<t, st>$

Comment: Anyway, do you know how to find the subgroups of order 5 for $D_{10}$? and I really appreciate you helping me with my question

Comment: Yes, it does. Since $s^2$ can be written as an expression involving $s$ and $t$ (since $s^2\in\langle s, t\rangle$), and $s$ can be written as an expression involving $t$ and $st$ (since $s\in\langle s, st\rangle$), it follows that $s^2$ can be written as an expression involving $s$ and $st$: in fact, $s^2  = (st)t(st)t)$.

Comment: @sara $s^2$ _is_ in $\langle t,st\rangle$. Remember that $t^2=e$. We have $s^2=(st)(t)(st)(t)$, therefore $s^2\in\langle t,st\rangle$.

Comment: Regarding subgroups of order 5, what do you know about the order of any element in a group of order 5?

Comment: sorry - that was wrong of me to pick that element because, as I wrote above, s $\in <t, st>$ so of course $s^2$ is too. BUT it is not a subset!

Comment: because s, st have order 2 so ($s^n$)($(st)^n$) either equals s, st, sst.

Comment: But it is! The argument I gave you for why $s^2$ is in $\langle s, st\rangle$ works for *any* element of $\langle s, t\rangle$.

Comment: and ($st^n)(s^n$) either equals s, st, sts (and e of course too). They are its only elements

Comment: I read this lemma in my notes - it says that if we have two subgroups H and K then <H, K> is also a subgroup - this is the lemma I have applied to find the subgroups of order 5 - have you seen this lemma before?

Comment: @rogerl, I understand what you are saying now - and my issue is that this conflicts with the lemma I've read - because $<t, st>$ must be a subgroup, unless $<t, st> = D_{10}$. Anyway - how do we find the subgroups then!?!?! Thank you :D

Comment: And in fact $\langle t, st\rangle = D_{10}$ (so it is still a subgroup, just not a proper subgroup). To find a subgroup of order 5, you want to find an element $x$ of order 5 and compute $\langle x\rangle$. Do you know any elements of order 5 in $D_{10}$?